# Encryption & Decryption from C# to php

Tags: php

I'm trying to convert this Ecryption and Decryption function from C# to php

```
public static string EncryptBySymmetricKey(string text, string sek) {
    //Encrypting SEK
    try {
        byte[] dataToEncrypt = Convert.FromBase64String(text);
        var keyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(sek);
        AesManaged tdes = new AesManaged();
        tdes.KeySize = 256;
        tdes.BlockSize = 128;
        tdes.Key = keyBytes;
        tdes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
        tdes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        ICryptoTransform encrypt__1 = tdes.CreateEncryptor();
        byte[] deCipher = encrypt__1.TransformFinalBlock(dataToEncrypt, 0, dataToEncrypt.Length);
        tdes.Clear();
        string EK_result = Convert.ToBase64String(deCipher);
        return EK_result;

    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        throw ex;
    }
}

public static byte[] DecryptBySymmetricKey(string encryptedText, byte[] key) {
    //Decrypting SEK
    try {
        byte[] dataToDecrypt = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedText);
        var keyBytes = key;
        AesManaged tdes = new AesManaged();
        tdes.KeySize = 256;
        tdes.BlockSize = 128;
        tdes.Key = keyBytes;
        tdes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
        tdes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        ICryptoTransform decrypt__1 = tdes.CreateDecryptor();
        byte[] deCipher = decrypt__1.TransformFinalBlock(dataToDecrypt, 0, dataToDecrypt.Length);
        tdes.Clear();

        string EK_result = Convert.ToBase64String(deCipher);
        return EK_result;
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Can anyone please help me out that what is the correct php code for the above C# function.
Here i just wanted the same C# code in php.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: and what is that error? in which sides? PHP or C# ?

Comment: Hi, please can you [edit] your question to be *as specific as possible*: what is the input you are testing with, what is the expected output, and what is the exact output or error message you see. See if you can put together a [mcve]: some code that someone could run themselves, and test their fixes.